# How can I use Work-space edge settings on Gnome-Classic

Tags: 12.04, workspaces, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome-Classic and I need to configure Work-space edge settings. In unity it can be easily done by Ubuntu tweak Tool...
this is what I had in unity

when hovering bottom left-Shows desktop, bottom right-Windows, top right-Workspaces

but there is no such setting in Ubuntu tweak in gnome-classic, how to enable Workspace edges?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To enable expo

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` with the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```

   or using this link [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]
2. While you are on the gnome-classic session, open it (compizconfig-settings-manager)
3. Click on the **Expo** plugin
4. Click on the **Expo** edge in **Bindings**  tab
5. Set the edge of your liking

Now the feature is enabled.

### To enable scale

1. Open compizconfig-settings-manager
2. Click on the **Scale** plugin
3. Click on the **Bindings** tab
4. Click on the **Initiate window picker** button
5. Set the edge of your liking. (I like the bottom-right).

Now, the scale is also enabled. As a bonus, Try also enabling the **Scale Addons** plugins. It will help you quickly close windows while you are on scale mood.

### To enable show desktop

1. Open compizconfig-settings-manager
2. Click on the **General** plugin
3. Click on the **key bindings** tab
4. Click on the **Show Desktop** icon. There are two icons. Click on the one which is showing a monitor, not a keyboard.
5. Set the edge of your liking there.

Comment: @Prasad don't forget to accept this if you think, it deserves it. Thanks